# Angular FormControl with Button Toggle Multiple

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have the following object

```
currentApplication = { 
          'Initial': [12, 2, true, true, false], 
          'Reminder1': [8, 2, true, true, false], 
          'Reminder2': [4, 2, true, true, false], 
          'Reminder3': [2, 2, true, true, false] 
        }
```

The 3rd, 4th and 5th value of the array represents the values I want for some Toggle Buttons shown below.

[image: toggle buttons]

In my component I have:

```
this.mySettingsForm = new FormGroup({
      audienceLearner: new FormControl(applicationSettings.Initial[2]),
      audienceLineManager: new FormControl(applicationSettings.Initial[3]),
      audienceClientAdmin: new FormControl(applicationSettings.Initial[4])
    })
```

in my HTML I have

```
 <form [formGroup]="mySettingsForm" autocomplete="off">
  <mat-button-toggle-group name="audience" aria-label="audience" multiple="true" >
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="applicationSettings.Initial[2]">Learner</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle value="manager">Line Manager</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle value="clientAdmin">Client Admin</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
 </form>
```

I was hoping that because the value in `applicationSettings.Initial[2]` is true that the button would appear pre-selected but it does not. If I use formControlName="audienceLearner" on the button I get an error: `No value accessor for form control with name: 'audienceLearner'`

So I need to get the buttons to show as pre-selected and I need to update the value when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `[value]="applicationSettings.Initial[2]"` you're setting the value the button passes when pressed to `true` instead of passing "learner". (I assume that's the intent since the other two buttons' values match their button text)

For `mat-button-toggle-group`, if you give it a `value` property equal to one of the `mat-toggle-button`s' values then the button with that value will appear pressed. For example, this would make the first button pressed by default:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="audience" aria-label="audience" multiple="true" value="learner" >
 <mat-button-toggle value="learner">Learner</mat-button-toggle>
 <mat-button-toggle value="manager">Line Manager</mat-button-toggle>
 <mat-button-toggle value="clientAdmin">Client Admin</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

When using `multiple="true"` the value is stored as an array. Pressing all three buttons would result in `["learner", "manager", "clientAdmin"]`. You will need some function to create a string array based on the boolean values in the object, then apply that array to the value property.